# LiveData with two sources?

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-architecture-components, mutablelivedata, mediatorlivedata

I'd like to use the same LiveData with different sources. One from an API call which is an observable and one from a database which is a LiveData. I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
private LiveData<List<Items>> items = new MutableLiveData<>();

// this one comes from an API and it's an observable
public void onApiItemsSelected(String name) {
 Disposable disposable = repository.getItemsFromApi(name)
 .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
 .subscribe(itemsList -> {
     items.setValue(itemsList);
 });

 compositeDisposable.add(disposable);
}

// this one comes from the database and it's a livedata that I want to transform first
public void onDatabaseItemsSelected() {
 items = Transformations.map(repository.getItemsFromdatabase(), itemsList -> {
    List<Items> finalItemsList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Item item : itemsList) {
      finalItemsList.add(itemsList.toSomething());
    }

    return finalItemsList;
 });
}
```

The problem is that a Transformation.map always returns a LiveData and in order to make a **items.setValue(itemsList)** items need to be a MutableLiveData. I tried with MediatorLiveData but it's calling the two sources and mixing everything. That's not what I need here. I need one source OR the other. Is it possible?

Comment: I am not sure what you trying to do. You want to combine those results or you want to access the latest result (like whichever is the latest database or api)?

Comment: If the user clicks on a button that calls onApiItemsSelected I want to display the values from the API and if he clicks on onDatabaseItemsSelected I want to display the values from the database. I don't want them to be combined. I want to display one or the other. They are the same object that will be displayed on the same list. Only the source is different.

Comment: I will try to post a code to help.

Comment: Why not always save the data from API to DB, and only show data from DB?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could delegate this responsibility to your repository.

See for example this [open source project](https://github.com/ryandt/JobTracker) and related [article](https://medium.com/@rtaza/android-mvvm-with-network-status-observables-ft-livedata-rxjava-room-listadapter-and-kotlin-a54c328c707b) with more info.

Basically, the repository handles all the complexity of deciding which source to get the data from (see the [JobRepository](https://github.com/ryandt/JobTracker/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/nerdery/rtaza/jobtracker/data/repository/JobRepository.kt)). It exposes a rx `Observable` to the `ViewModel` (see the [JobsViewModel](https://github.com/ryandt/JobTracker/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/nerdery/rtaza/jobtracker/ui/jobs/JobsViewModel.kt)). Then all the ViewModel has to do is update the `LiveData`:

```
private val presentation: MutableLiveData<Presentation> = MutableLiveData()

fun bind() {
        jobRepository.getJobs(true)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe { resource: Resource<List<JobWithRelations>> ->
                when (resource) {
                    // commenting some parts for brevity ...
                    is Resource.ResourceFound -> {
                        presentation.postValue(Presentation(getApplication(), resource.data!!))
                    }
                    // ...
                }
            }.addTo(compositeDisposable)
    }
```

Managing multiple sources of data is complex. Among the many aspects involved in architecting this, things to keep in mind include:

- In-memory caching expiration strategies
- Policies for db caching, for example, when users are offline
- Throttling and retry of API calls
- Policies for updating the in-memory cache or db when new data comes from the network

One library that could help you is the Dropbox [Store](https://github.com/dropbox/Store). With it, you could build your data sources like in the example below from their documentation:

```
StoreBuilder
    .from(
        fetcher = nonFlowValueFetcher { api.fetchSubreddit(it, "10").data.children.map(::toPosts) },
        sourceOfTruth = SourceOfTrue.from(
            reader = db.postDao()::loadPosts,
            writer = db.postDao()::insertPosts,
            delete = db.postDao()::clearFeed,
            deleteAll = db.postDao()::clearAllFeeds
        )
    ).build()
```

Then to get the data in your ViewModel:

```
private val presentation: MutableLiveData<Presentation> = MutableLiveData()

lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
  store.stream(StoreRequest.cached(key = key, refresh=true)).collect { response ->
    when(response) {
        // commenting some parts for brevity ...
        is StoreResponse.Data -> {
            presentation.postValue(response.value)
        }
        // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the very well explained answer. I'll give it a try ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it is the best practice but I think will do the trick.

```
public void onDatabaseItemsSelected() {
items.value = repository.getItemsFromdatabase().value;
};
```

The syntax may not be accurate as I am know little about java, I do mainly kotlin. But the thing is: when the user clicks Api, make your onApiItemsSelected() run, that will set the value of **items**, when the user clicks database, make **onDatabaseItemsSelected()** run, so it will replace **items** value for the result of **repository.getItemsFromDatabase()**

Comment: This only works if you are lucky, which is probably never (it definitely would not work if the `getItemsFromDatabase` is a LiveData from a Room DAO).